# How to use values stated in the if-else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, sharpdevelop

I have recently started studying C# and I wanted to make a length converter with different units. However, it seems that I cannot use values stated inside the if-else statement. Can anyone please help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace converter
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void ClearBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convIn.Clear();
        convOut.Clear();
        cmbConv.Refresh();
    }
    void ExitBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    void ConvBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { double exchangeRate;

        if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Miles to Kilometers")
        {
            exchangeRate = 1.60934;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Kilometers to Miles")
        {
            exchangeRate = 0.621371;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Inches to Centimeters")
        {
            exchangeRate = 0.393701;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Centimeters to Inches")
        {
            exchangeRate = 2.54;
        }

        double conv = Convert.ToDouble(convIn.Text);
        var conversion = conv * exchangeRate;

        var result = Convert.ToString(conversion);

        convOut.Text = result;
        }

    }
}
```

Before I used this, I used a different structure which also didn´t work, in which I separated the if-else statement in different methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace converter
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void ClearBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convIn.Clear();
        convOut.Clear();
        cmbConv.Refresh();
    }
    void ExitBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    void ConvBClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           double conv = Convert.ToDouble(convIn.Text);
        var conversion = conv * exchangeRate;

        var result = Convert.ToString(conversion);

        convOut.Text = result;
    }
    void CmbConvSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         double exchangeRate;

        if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Miles to Kilometers")
        {
            exchangeRate = 1.60934;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Kilometers to Miles")
        {
            exchangeRate = 0.621371;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Inches to Centimeters")
        {
            exchangeRate = 0.393701;
        }
        else if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Centimeters to Inches")
        {
            exchangeRate = 2.54;
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: `it seems that I cannot use values stated inside the if-else statement`; what's the error? because it's valid C#.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax or scoping of the variables, is it possible that you are not reaching the statements inside if? That is, those if-expressions are for some reason never evaluated to true? Because then, you would never get the value.

Comment: You need to make sure that your variable always has a value.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a variable called `exchangeRate` in your `ConvBClick` method, but that variable doesn't exist in that method.  You created a similarly named variable in your `CmbConvSelectedIndexChanged` method, but then never did anything with it.

More to the overall structure of the code however, your `CmbConvSelectedIndexChanged` method doesn't really do anything.  It executes any time the selected index changes on that control, but it doesn't affect anything else.  Instead of responding to that `SelectedIndexChanged` event at all, just write a method which returns the value you want based on whatever the current selected index is:

```
double GetExchangeRate()
{
    double exchangeRate = 0.0;

    if(cmbConv.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Miles to Kilometers")
    {
        exchangeRate = 1.60934;
    }
    // etc., the rest of your conditions

    return exchangeRate;
}
```

Then in your button click you can just call that method to get the current exchange rate:

```
double conv = Convert.ToDouble(convIn.Text);
var exchangeRate = GetExchangeRate();
var conversion = conv * exchangeRate;

var result = Convert.ToString(conversion);

convOut.Text = result;
```